# Create SASS like global variables, functions, mixins with styled components

Tags: sass, next.js, styled-components

I'm starting a new project that uses styled components.  I'm used to an architecture in SASS where I have something like:

```
styles
  mixins
    custom-mixin.scss
    ...
    all-mixins.scss
  variables
    colors.scss
    breakpoints.scss
    ...
    all-variables.scss
  mixins-and-variables.scss
```

Normally, I'd import `mixins-and-variables.scss` in my project head.  I was hoping to change this to a pattern like so for my JS files using styled components:

```
styles
src
  head.js <<< imports mixins-and-variables.scss
```

This would make my mixins and variables accessible globally to any stylesheet I've imported underneath of it, such as:

```
styles
src
  head.js
  components
    section.js
    section.module.scss <<< can access global variables sourced in head.js
```

With styled components, I'm having a hard time with a global pattern as each component is scoped to itself.  I would like to avoid having to import all of my utility files in each styled component.  Is there any way to replicate the above pattern in a styled component way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use/mix [global styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle), [themes](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming), [tagged template literals](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#tagged-template-literals) (mixins/variables), and [extend styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) to achieve your goals.